# Linq query returns half the results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am making an intranet Website using asp.NET MVC5 and Entity Framework for Data Access. I have two tables `Web_Documents` and `Web_Profiles` and a relation's table `Web_Profile_joint_Document`. Now to retrieve the `Documents` I want, I have to use `IDProfile` of `Web_Profiles` table. Then using this, I can find documents in the relation's table. One problem though, the query I make returns half the results I want. In the test I am making I have 2 `IDProfile`, values being `120 & 124`. Here is my query:

```
IEnumerable<Web_Documents> retrieveDocuments;
List<int> idProfiles = new List<int>();
idProfiles.Add(120);
idProfiles.Add(124);  
foreach (var item in idProfiles)
{
    var idDocument = context.WebProfils
                    .Where(c => c.IDProfil == item)
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Documents).ToList();


    if (idDocument != null)
    {
         if (retrieveDocuments == null)
         {
              retrieveDocuments = idDocument;
         }
         else
         {
              retrieveDocuments.Concat(idDocument);
         }
}
```

Since `Web_Profiles` and `Web_Documents` have a relation, I can access `ICollection <Web_Documents> Documents` which is in `Web_Profiles` POCO (entity). I then store results in `retrieveDocuments`. But this returns only the values for `IDProfile=120`. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

**Remark** All answers are good!

Comment: The query returns what you tell it to return - one Profile at a time.

Comment: hmm, so you saying the error comes from somewhere else?

Comment: No, I'm saying there is no error. You are asking for only one profile at a time

Comment: Try to change the Concat with an AddRange or read the answer below (delete the foreach and add Contains to the query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query as it is loads one profile at a time. It's not returning half the results, it's returing the results it was asked to return.

In SQL, you'd use an `IN` clause to return records that match multiple IDs, eg `WHERE ID IN (1,4,7)`.

In LINQ, you can do the same by creating a list/array of values and using `Contains` :

```
var profiles = new[]{120,124};
var retrievedDocuments = context.WebProfils
                .Where(c => profiles.Contains(c.IDProfil))
                .SelectMany(c => c.Documents)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: The query does not return half the result. The query returns all the result. In the code above the problem is the concat.

Comment: I marked this as answer because it was best explained though bubi had the same code

Comment: @bubi I think that matches the first sentence in my answer. The *actual* problem is the entire snippet. It tries to do in multiple steps what can be done in a single one

Comment: When you change an answer you could mark the changes with **EDIT** :)

Comment: @bubi only if it's necessary. It's an *answer* not a blog post. In this case I *removed* code once I realized the entire `if` block wasn't needed. The text didn't change

Answer (score 3):

Concat returns a new list. You need to either do

```
retrieveDocuments = retrieveDocuments.Concat(idDocument);
```

or

```
retrieveDocuments.AddRange(idDocument);
```

Comment: I'm trying thanks! Though AddRange method is not available for an IEnumeration, but I can always change to List. The Concat  works! Thanks  a bunch!

Comment: Better yet, return all results at once. There's no need for the loop or the concatenations or the multiple lists and enumerables

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the foreach and change your query in this way

```
var idDocument = context.WebProfils
                .Where(c => idProfiles.Contains(c.IDProfil))
                .SelectMany(c => c.Documents).ToList();


if (idDocument != null) // Not required. idDocument can't be null (but can be empty)
{
     // Now the following lines are not required
     if (retrieveDocuments == null)
     {
          retrieveDocuments = idDocument;
     }
     else
     {
          retrieveDocuments.Concat(idDocument);
     }
}
```

Comment: In what way and why?  I can see the change but I'm certain the OP can't, and won't understand *why* the change works

Comment: Yes retrieveDocuments is null at first iteration, it's an IEnumerable, I did this to avoid an exception

Comment: @LéonardLaiter What they're saying is, you don't need that entire codeblock because you've already retrieved all the documents in one query.

Comment: retrieveDocuments is no more required because idDocument contains all the required documents (idDocument = old retrieveDocuments)

Comment: This answer also saves on roundtrips to the database which is desirable.

Comment: @J.Steen But the query runs twice, so how can idDocument be filled up with two different queries? I will try

Comment: @LéonardLaiter That's the point. The query doesn't run twice. Bubi has removed the foreach.

Comment: Now, the database provider you use might not support the query bubi has written, but that's a different matter. There's always a way to make it work. And like I said - reducing the number of roundtrips is far more desirable.

Comment: @J.Steen haha, yes you are right I was still looking at my code. Ok cool thanks guys!

Comment: @LéonardLaiter, the query ends with a ToList so idDocument will Always be a list (an empty list if no records). Also, you avoid a round trip because the idProfiles.Contains that EF converts in IdProfil IN (120, 124)

Comment: @J.Steen do you have in mind any provider that can't handle `IN` clauses ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, but I'm sure there are some where the Linq-to-whatever provider hasn't implemented a transform for `Contains` to `IN`.

Comment: @bubi if you check the code, `retrievedDocuments` is essentially an alias for the returned results. It's not needed once you create a single query. You could write just `var retrievedDocuments = context.WebProfils ...`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've read the code and there were different errors. 1. Contains and that's why the code did not work. 2. The check idDocuments != null, idDocuments can't be null after a ToList 3. The double roundtrip. Here you can see the commented errors in that code.

Answer (score -1):

Replace Your Code

```
retrieveDocuments=retrieveDocuments.Concat(idDocument);
```